# LINQ to find count of all Datapoints in ASP.NET Chart

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, linq, asp.net-charts

I have

```
Chart1["Series1"]
Chart1["Series2"] ....
```

It has multiple Series and each series has Several Data points.

I want to find the count ( not sum but number of datapoints ) of  Data points in all the series using LINQ.

Currently i do

```
var count = from s in Chart1.Series
            select new int[] { s.Points.Count };
```

And then for each thorough count and find the sum. Is there a better way to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var total = Chart1.Series.Sum(s => s.Points.Count);
```